# Read/Write directly to Linux files from Windows using editor

Tags: linux, centos, mount, smb, cifs

Is there a way to mount and share a linux directory so Windows can access it?

I would like to read/write directly to files from a text editor for quicker live development with Apache

Running CentOS 7 with GRSec kernel.

Comment: Is the server on your local network? Are you looking for SMB/CIFS?

Comment: Yea, SMB or CIFS. I did some searching and found some CIFS solutions people said worked, but that was from mid 2000s and had no success. I just don't like working on Windows with a LAMP solution since I prefer running a dedicated HTTP environment in Linux. Right now my current solution is to just FTP the files as I make changes but I would like to just cut out the middle step

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit a file through HTTP. For local servers, Samba shares are definitely the easiest for Windows to deal with. Another option if a software called SSHFS, which uses an interface that looks like a directory but connects to the server through SSH.